Memory issues while using Dask
Problem
I need to combine data from the Orbis firm database with data on syndicated loans from the Dealscan syndicated loan database. Unfortunately, the Dealscan-specific identifiers for the firms (i.e. the borrowers) are not compatible with the Orbis-specific firm identifiers. Fortunately, about half of the firms in Dealscan have a LEI identifier, which is common to both databases.
Task
1.       For every Dealscan Borrower ID find the corresponding BVDIDNUMBER in Orbis
2.       The files are gigantic, which makes it necessary to work with Dask. (Orbis - 200 GB of txt.file)
3.       In most cases, I am uncertain whether the firm I found in Orbis is the same as the firm I searched for from Dealscan, for example, because there is a typo in Dealscan
4.       To be as efficient as possible, I first restrict the set of firms in Orbis to those from the same country, city and first letter and then look for the firm with the closest name within the list of remaining names
5.       I use Python package fuzzywuzzy which has the function “extractOne”.
The code is below:
### I ### Data preparation

# Loading dta. files into pandas dataframe
file_path_dealscan = 'C:\\Users\\f-komiss\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject_Matching\\Firm_data_from_Dealscan.dta'
pandas_df = pd.read_stata(file_path_dealscan, columns=["BorrowerName", "Country", "City", "bvdidnumber"])
pandas_df['First_Letter'] = pandas_df['BorrowerName'].str[0]  # Add First_Letter column
dask_df_dealscan = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=10)


# load the Orbis-file contact info
filepath = "I:\\!Databases\\Amadeus"
dd_contactinfo = dd.read_csv("%s\\Contact_info.txt"%filepath,sep='\t',assume_missing=True, on_bad_lines='skip',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dtype={'BvD ID number':object,
'NAME_INTERNAT':object,'City':object,'Country':object}, usecols=['BvD ID number', 'NAME_INTERNAT', 'City', 'Country'],  blocksize=100 * 10**6)

dask_df_orbis = dd_contactinfo

dask_df_orbis['First_Letter'] = dask_df_orbis['NAME_INTERNAT'].str[0]  # Add First_Letter column.


# Filter based on City, Country, and First Letter
dask_df_orbis = dask_df_orbis[
    dask_df_orbis['City'].isin(pandas_df['City'].unique()) &
    dask_df_orbis['Country'].isin(pandas_df['Country'].unique()) &
    dask_df_orbis['First_Letter'].isin(pandas_df['First_Letter'].unique())
]





### II ### Matching function

### Create a list of matched names###
# Define a delayed function for matching
def match_names(row, df_with_id):
    name, country, city, first_letter = row['BorrowerName'], row['Country'], row['City'], row['First_Letter']
    filtered_df_with_id = df_with_id[(df_with_id['Country'] == country) & (df_with_id['City'] == city) & (df_with_id['First_Letter'] == first_letter)]
    if not filtered_df_with_id.empty:
        best_match = process.extractOne(name, filtered_df_with_id['NAME_INTERNAT'])
        if best_match is not None:
            matched_id_orbis = filtered_df_with_id.loc[filtered_df_with_id['NAME_INTERNAT'] == best_match[0], 'BvD ID number'].values[0]
            return pd.Series([best_match[0], best_match[1], matched_id_orbis])
    return pd.Series([None, None, None])

def process_partition(partition, df_with_id):
    return partition.apply(lambda row: match_names(row, df_with_id), axis=1)


delayed_orbis = delayed(dask_df_orbis)
# Applying the function to each partition
meta = {0: 'object', 1: 'int', 2: 'object'}
matched_names_dd = dask_df_dealscan.map_partitions(process_partition, delayed_orbis, meta=meta)
matched_names_dd_renamed = matched_names_dd.rename(columns={0: "Matched_name", 1: "Matched_Score", 2: "Matched_ID"})


# Merge the matched names with the original dealscan DataFrame
result_dd = dd.concat([dask_df_dealscan, matched_names_dd_renamed], axis=1)

# Select relevant columns
result_dd = result_dd[['BorrowerName', 'bvdidnumber', 'Matched_name', 'Matched_Score', "Matched_ID"]]

print(result_dd)

It functions well on a small sample data, but while using on the main dataset I receive memory issues. Can you please advise how this could be avoided?
I have tried to execute the code in batching, using from_delayed, but it did not work out. As of now, it takes around half an hour for compute() to run and then code execution stops at 99% or crushed due to lack of memory
Thank you,

How are you launching the above computation in the end? You are mentionning a call to compute()?
